# Extractes files are encoded wrong with ZipArchive

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I get several external ZIP Files which contain a number of files with UTF-8 characters. 
So now when I'm extracting the file I get many errors in the filenames.

I tried some solutions out of the web such as:

```
$zipAmountOfFiles = $zip->numFiles;
for($i = 0; $i < $zipAmountOfFiles; $i++)
{
    $filename = $zip->getNameIndex($i);
    $zip->addFile(str_replace($umlaute, $umschreibungUmlaute, $filename));
    $zip->deleteIndex($i);
}
```

I also tried to use renameIndex.

```
for($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++)
{
    $oldFilename = $zip->getNameIndex($i);
    $newFilename = str_replace($umlaute, $umschreibungUmlaute, $oldFilename);
    $zip->renameIndex($i, $newFilename);
}
```

Nothing works on the file.